# Loop through getJson result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having trouble to loop through returned JSON result. If the result matches some requirements then append them to a `<li>` element. Yes I'm still learning :)

The returned result looks like this `[text][text2][text3]bla,blabla, blabla`.
I want only to grab the elements between brackets. Afterwards these brackets need to be removed and the cleaned result should be placed in a `<li>` element.

So what I have is this:

```
 $.getJSON('some-url?format=json', function(e) {

   var keywords = e.shop.keywords; //result = [text][text2][text3]bla,blabla, blabla

    $(keywords).each(function(i, keys) {
      var keys = keywords.match(/\[(.*?)\]/); //matches if text is between brackets

       if (keys) {
         var submatch = keys[1];
        }
     });

   $('.some-div ul').html('<li>'+submatch+'</li>');

 });
```

Doing it like above gives me an error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [text][text2][text3]`

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: you should pass an array to `each()` function ...

Comment: `keywords` is a string, right? Wrapping a string in `$()` does not automagically convert it to an array, and even if it did, the syntax you're using would be wrong. See the API http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ how to use `$.each()`

Comment: if `[text][text2][text3]bla,blabla, blabla` is your JSON, it's completely messed up/invalid, and I wonder that your script didn't throw an Error. *Edit:* It seems that this is exactly the Error you get. **fix the data that's returned by the server to be valid JSON**

Comment: @Thomas: Excuse me for not mentioning that the actual data is returned as "[text]". It's just plain, simple and valid JSON

Comment: @Thomas that error is b/c of passing an invalid selector to jQuery: `$("[text][etc]")`.  The JSON response will be coming in through the param `e` to the anon function.  If e.shop.keywords is coming through as a string, that suggests the JSON *is* valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that `e.shop.keywords` is a string you wish to perform a regular expression upon, simply use JavaScript's regex `String#match` function and loop over the result using `Array#forEach`:

```
$.getJSON('some-url?format=json', function(e) {
  // if e.shop.keywords is string "[text][text2][text3]bla,blabla, blabla"
  // perform a regex match on the string...  and loop over using forEach
  var result = e.shop.keywords.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g);
  if( result ) {
    result.forEach(function(text){
      // since we're dealing with the entire match rather than match group 1
      // we'll want to chop off the first "[" and last char "]" via substring
      $('.some-div ul').append('<li>'+text.substring(1,text.length-1)+'</li>');
      // also: use append rather than html to avoid overwriting previous li elements
    });
  }
});
```

The above will output:

```
<li>text</li>
<li>text2</li>
<li>text3</li>
```

Which you can test independent of your AJAX call:

```
"[text][text2][text3]bla,blabla, blabla".match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g).forEach(function(text){
  console.log('<li>'+text.substring(1,text.length-1)+'</li>');
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly! However one little tiny thing... When the string doesn't match it returns `null`.

Comment: Good catch, @Meules.  The snippet has been updated to verify that a result was returned from `String#match`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use a selector on a string: `$(keywords)`.  This is most certainly not what you want to do.  I can see the confusion here, as is looks as if you were expecting `keywords` to be an array when it is not.

Instead, you should use the regular expression `.match()` on the string you've referenced via `var keywords = e.shop.keywords;`.  Then, you should interate over the 'match array' like so:

```
$.getJSON('some-url?format=json', function(e) {

    var keywords = e.shop.keywords; //result = [text][text2][text3]bla,blabla, blabla
    var keys = keywords.match(/\[(.*?)\]/); //matches if text is between brackets

    $.each(keys, function(index, value) {
       //Here, index is the index of the array keys
       //value is the matched string.
       $('.some-div ul').append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
    });
});
```